# Restructuring Table in Django Model

Tags: python, sql-server, django

I'm building a Django web interface for legacy systems that currently use MS Access as a front end for an MSSQL database. We have two similar test stands that report similar data, but in two different ways. The older one puts all of the results in one table with a column for each step of the test, and the other one uses a related table, as it was designed to have different numbers of steps.

My question is, can I create a model that turns the first table into a master and lookup table?

Start Table:

```
+-----+---------+--------+-----------+----------------+----------+----------------+----------------+----------+----------------+-------------+---------------+
| ID  | PartNum | Serial | Pass/Fail | Test A 1 Upper | Test A 1 | Test A 1 Lower | Test A 2 Upper | Test A 2 | Test A 2 Lower | Test B Done | Test B Passed |
+-----+---------+--------+-----------+----------------+----------+----------------+----------------+----------+----------------+-------------+---------------+
| 123 |     991 |    111 | T         |           10.0 |        8 |              6 |             15 |       13 |             12 | T           | T             |
| 124 |     991 |    112 | F         |           10.0 |        9 |              6 |             15 |       16 |             12 | T           | T             |
| 125 |     991 |    113 | F         |           10.0 |        7 |              6 |             15 |       14 |             12 | T           | F             |
+-----+---------+--------+-----------+----------------+----------+----------------+----------------+----------+----------------+-------------+---------------+
```

End Tables:

```
Master
+-----+---------+--------+-----------+
| ID  | PartNum | Serial | Pass/Fail |
+-----+---------+--------+-----------+
| 123 |     991 |    111 | T         |
| 124 |     991 |    112 | F         |
| 125 |     991 |    113 | T         |
+-----+---------+--------+-----------+

Test A:
+-----+--------+------+-------+-------+-------+------+
| ID  | TestID | Test | Upper | Value | Lower | Pass |
+-----+--------+------+-------+-------+-------+------+
| 211 |    123 |    1 |    10 |     8 |     6 | T    |
| 212 |    123 |    2 |    15 |    13 |    12 | T    |
| 213 |    124 |    1 |    10 |     9 |     6 | T    |
| 214 |    124 |    2 |    15 |    16 |    12 | F    |
| 215 |    125 |    1 |    10 |     7 |     6 | T    |
| 216 |    125 |    2 |    15 |    14 |    12 | T    |
+-----+--------+------+-------+-------+-------+------+

Test B:
+-----+--------+------+--------+
| ID  | TestID | Done | Passed |
+-----+--------+------+--------+
| 311 |    123 | T    | T      |
| 312 |    124 | T    | T      |
| 313 |    125 | T    | F      |
+-----+--------+------+--------+
```

Obviously the solution won't be simple, I'm more asking if it's doable/feasible. I would like both of the databases to be the same, just so that similar queries can be run on the data. The newer test stand has the layout that I prefer, so I'm hoping to match the old one to the new one.

Answer (score 0):

Your model won't do database migration for you in this case.
You can manually migrate database and write models for new structure.

If you need to work with both structures of the database at the same time, you'll have to write additional code that will behave differently depending on which base it is currently working with.